# SQL Server where clause statement do not work on certain "columns"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am creating a website in ASPX which can pull out a data from the database (LocalDB) using a where clause function. Currently, I am trying to pull out a column "Message" where user='xxx'.

Here is my statement:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=myConnectionString");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Message FROM Enquiry WHERE User = 'abc'"); 
    command.Connection = conn; 

    conn.Open(); 
    string value = (string)command.ExecuteScalar(); 
    conn.Close(); 

    Label1.Text = value;
}
```

The problem is that it does not pull out any data if I used "User" in the where clause, however it does work if I use "Id" or other columns.

**Does not work**

```
SELECT Message 
FROM Enquiry 
WHERE User = 'abc';
```

**This works**

```
SELECT Message 
FROM Enquiry 
WHERE Id = '1';
```

I have tried to look for any misspelling but when using a break-point, the value returned is a null value. There is no spelling error whatsoever, does anyone encounter this before?

Comment: can you post the record where user name is 'abc'

Comment: My guess is that your data has a problem, either missing data, or usernames with characters of which you are not aware.  Try this query: `SELECT Message FROM Enquiry where User LIKE '%abc%'` ... what result do you get?

Comment: @Abi Im supposed to get a result "testtest" when I execute but nothing is showing up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hi, i have checked my database and there is no error at all :( I have tried ur query but it still returned a "null" value.

Comment: Then maybe this data is missing from your table.  Next do `SELECT User FROM Enquiry` ... do you see `abc` appearing anywhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I get a value called "dbo"..

Comment: Well if you don't see `abc` then now you know the reason for that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I followed the others who mentioned to use [user], it kind of worked for me! Thanks for your help anyway, cheers :)

Comment: Why did you tag MySQL if you're using SQL Server?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tagged sql, asp.net and visual-studio only!

Comment: No, you tagged MySQL also.  I have removed that tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh, I might have typed wrongly! My bad..

Answer (score 4):

Did you really use `User` as the name for your column?

If so the try this using this `[User]`.

As far as I know `USER` is a reserved word from SQL Server.

*It should be something like:*

```
SELECT Message 
FROM Enquiry 
WHERE [User] = 'abc'
```

Comment: The OP is using MySQL AFAIK, not SQL Server.

Comment: Well that helped! I did not know that User is a reserved word, thanks alot!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim, as i read from his statement "SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=myConnectionString");
" not MySqlConnection

Answer (score 2):

```
`User`
```

Is Reserved word in sql.
You can try below code

```
SELECT Message FROM Enquiry where `User`='abc'
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Use is not a reserved keyword.